# Remove the edges of an input in ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

I am currently developing an app on ionic v4 and my problems is that I can not remove the edges of the focus, previously in ionic v3 only these lines of code are placed in variable.css and ready but in this version it does not work, thanks

```
  $text-input-md-highlight-color-invalid: transparent;
  $text-input-md-highlight-color-valid: transparent;
  $text-input-md-show-invalid-highlight: transparent;
  $text-input-md-highlight-color: transparent;
  $text-input-md-show-valid-highlight: transparent;
  $text-input-md-show-focus-highlight: transparent;
  $text-input-md-show-valid-highlight: $text-input-md-show-focus-highlight transparent;
  $text-input-md-show-invalid-highlight: $text-input-md-show-focus-highlight transparent;
```

[image]

Comment: ionic 4 does _not_ use sass variables. They use css variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In Ionic 4 it's like that:**

```
ion-item {
  --highlight-color-valid: transparent;
  --highlight-color-invalid: transparent;
  --highlight-color-focused: var(--ion-color-light);
}
```

**Official information:** 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item

Comment: Have you ever encountered an error on Microsoft Edge, where you specify your answer in root scss file, but MS Edge still colors the border, and will only react to component level styling, for example:  <ion-item style="--highlight-color-valid: transparent;"></ion-item>

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are using inside an item. Then you can do this

```
.item{
    --border-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with JP Torrellas. Put in **global.scss**:

```
ion-item {
    --highlight-color-valid: transparent;
    --highlight-color-invalid: transparent;
    --highlight-color-focused: var(--ion-color-light);
  }
```

Comment: If you are agree with someone's answer you should not add another answer, you can vote up and comment.

Comment: unfortunately i'm unable to comment yet